# Should I use a square-root transformation to linearize a relationship between a covariate and a dependent variable?

Tags: data-transformation, ancova, predictor

I'm running an ANCOVA (with a categorical independent variable and a continuous dependent variable).

The covariate is a continuous variable, which has a power-law relationship with the dependent variable. This is roughly similar to the the image below, where on the Y axis we have the dependent variable, and on the X axis we have the covariate.

[image]

Since one of the assumptions for an ANCOVA is a linear relationship between the covariate and the dependent variable, does it make sense to do a square-root transformation of the covariate in this case in order to linearize the relationship? If not, what would be an appropriate thing to do in this case, in order to run the test with all the assumptions being met?

Comment: What matters is not the relationship between the two variables, but the relationship *after controlling for* all other variables in the model--including the categorical independent variable.  Although it's often the case that a qualitatively nonlinear relationship will persist after controlling for the other variables, it's worth checking.  Then you can study the relationships among the residuals (using only the categorical variables as regressors) using standard EDA techniques.